# App crashes when calling FlatUIKit methods on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I downloaded and added the classes from [FlatUIKit](https://github.com/Grouper/FlatUIKit) manually to my Xcode project (as installing it via CocoaPods wouldn't download some classes, like `UITableViewCell+FlatUI`)... Whenever I try to call one of the methods from any of FlatUIKit classes, the app crashes, and this gets displayed on Xcode:

[image]

Log:

```
    CoreFoundation`__CFTypeCollectionRetain:
0x33d5e260:  push   {r4, r7, lr}
0x33d5e262:  mov    r4, r1
0x33d5e264:  add    r7, sp, #4
0x33d5e266:  cbnz   r4, 0x33d5e274            ; __CFTypeCollectionRetain + 20
0x33d5e268:  trap   
0x33d5e26a:  blx    0x33dc7a4c                ; symbol stub for: -[NSOrderedSet intersectsSet:]
0x33d5e26e:  movs   r1, #9
0x33d5e270:  blx    0x33dc7b1c                ; symbol stub for: __61-[NSOrderedSet sortedArrayFromRange:options:usingComparator:]_block_invoke_0
0x33d5e274:  mov    r0, r4
0x33d5e276:  pop.w  {r4, r7, lr}
0x33d5e27a:  b.w    0x33cc7d1c                ; CFRetain
0x33d5e27e:  nop
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with ARC? How can I solve this? Here is example code that gives the EXC_BREAKPOINT

```
    FUIButton *button = [FUIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(loginButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Iniciar Sesión" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80, 210, 140, 40);

button.buttonColor = [UIColor turquoiseColor];
button.shadowColor = [UIColor greenSeaColor];
button.shadowHeight = 3.0f;
button.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldFlatFontOfSize:16];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor cloudsColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor cloudsColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[[self ScrollView]addSubview:button];

NSLog(@"Oks");
```

Comment: The image is not available. Maybe you can just copy and paste the crash log.

Comment: are you using ARC in your project?

Comment: Yes I am... I tried enabling ARC manually for each of the files, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with this kit..

Comment: Nikhita — Check my own answer to this question, below.

Answer (score 3):

After some tests, FlatUIKit's not longer crashing for me as It was when I posted this question. I think the problem somehow has to do with the library being installed via CocoaPods.

To avoid this problem, I now download de .zip directly from the project page at GitHub, and add it to my project manually. **Make sure you drag and drop the "Resources" folder too into your project,** as it contains the fonts used by FlatUIKit.

Whenever I need FlatUIKit, I now install it manually, and it haven't crashed for me anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Are you including CoreText.framework in your project? FlatUIKit requires that framework.

Also I see you are using the flat font. Those need to be included as well in your project